# python docker file with dependencies

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to create a python docker image for 1 script with the following dependencies,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import nltk
import string
import collections

import re
import os
import codecs
import mpld3
import sklearn
```

would I need a Dockerfile and is there a better documented sample than what I found on the official site?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean to install these packages from the pypi?

Comment: yes, 
do I just need `RUN pip3 install <package>` for all the packages?

Comment: The Dockerfile system is pretty simple; [here's an official Docker tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/).  You absolutely should be using it.  The [Python setuptools system](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is more complex but pretty well established, and if you're looking at packaging your script in any way (even into a Docker image) probably writing a valid `setup.py` for it is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a Dockerfile that looks something like this :

```
FROM python 
COPY requirements.txt /home/
RUN pip install -r /home/requirements.txt
```

Where requirements is all the packages you want to install.